# Смещение ударений в иностранных словах

Tags: орфоэпия, ономастика, заимствования

Почему в русском произношении некоторых иноязычных слов смещается ударение? Например, по-английски *Фло́рида*, а по-русски говорят *Флори́да*, по-японски *А́кира Куросава* (хотя в японском ударными являются все слоги, но на "и" после "к" там никак не может падать ударение), а по-русски — *Аки́ра*?

Answer (score 1):

Википедия говорит. что:

> Нет последовательной системной корреляции между орфографией слов и фонологией, то есть, не зная заранее традиционного произношения, не всегда можно правильно прочесть слово «с листа».

Судя по всему в русском ударение чаще попадает на предпоследний слог, в английском же наоборот на первый, либо вовсе кто в лес, кто по дрова.
У японцев вообще все слоги словно бы ударные, поэтому при заимствовании или переводе возникает русское ударение

Comment: >У японцев вообще все слоги словно бы ударные  
  
Не совсем так. См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе - да, фонетика (ударение в частности) при заимствованиях всегда приспосабливается под строй языка-мишени. Хотя в отношении имен собственных это может быть и не самая удачная идея. Но с языком не поспоришь.

Если разбираться с конкретными примерами, то да, ФлОрида - это по-английски. но ведь есть еще и испанский вариант, там-то как раз ФлорИда.
Насчет японского. Я не знаток, любопытства ради интересовался отдельными вещами на уровне общей лингвистики. Никогда не слышал, чтобы там были какие-то ограничения на ударный слог, в том числе - и на "ки"(き).
Тут другое. Японское ударение необязательное, а по способу - тоническое, оно никак не связано с напряжением, громкостью или длинной звука. Только с высотой. В русской традиции это как ударение не воспринимается и никак не передаётся. Отсюда и стремление поставить его там, где "красивше", т.е. там где это более всего соответствовало бы русским представлениям о месте ударения в подобных словах. Обычно это предпоследний слог.

В английском, кстати, ударение падает не на первый слог, а на третий с конца. Просто четырехсложных (и более) слов очень немного. И это обычно не касается заимствованных слов, особенно из французского, такие слова часто сохраняют место ударения языка-источника.